# How to get selected text from input field

Tags: javascript, input, markdown, user-input

Let's suppose I'm making some kind of markdown something like a stack-over-flow markdown. I want to get selected text from input and do some action with it

[image: Reference]

**something like this!**

**Here** The Selected Text is `Hello`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
window.getSelection().toString()
```

it'll get the highlighted or selected text within the page

Comment: How can i know text is from input box?

Comment: @Zain_Ul_Din, [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) returns a Selection object representing the range of text selected by the user or the current position of the caret.